# last question auto populates into the question form

Tags: support

I am trying to post a new question.  However, when I click on "ask question" I see the previous question that I posted auto populated into the title, text, and tag fields.  I want to still keep that previous question active.  If I overwrite my new question with my old question, will that overwrite my old question?

Comment: All you are seeing is a previously saved draft, it will not over write your other question, that cannot be done. Feel free to remove the added text and ask a question as normal.

Comment: @MarkKirby That seems like an answer ;)